# How to start up mate desktop

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment

We have had Fedora 20 installed on my wife's laptop, and want to use Mate as the default desktop displayed. The machine is set up to require no user password, but at reset there is no gear wheel to choose the desktop. The current desktop (Gnome 3?) does not seem to have access to systems settings that allow the change. Please, how do we go about this.

I have happily set up and use Mate on two other machines, desktop (tower) and laptop, but, of course, have forgotten the procedure I used, I don't recall it being difficult.

I have done:`# yum groupinstall Mate-desktop`
and (I might have this wrong from memory, and have mislaid the reference, but the response is correct)  `# yum install @mate-desktop` gives `nothing to do`.

Please, no answers suggesting other desktops, we have made the choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer was that I had set up my wife's account with no password, so the login stage and screen were by-passed. Now we have added a password the little gearwheel icon is there and clicking it gives the choice of Gnome or Mate, as desired.